# How does the term "API" differ in the phrases "Fetch API" and "REST API"?

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api

"API" seems to have two completely different meanings in "Fetch API" and "REST API". The former being a method to fetch data from a server - the latter being some server that you can fetch data from.

Comment: Seems a fair question to me, because I used to wonder about these 2 apparently unrelated meanings of the term. According to Wikipedia, a "web API" - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API is something slightly different from, although related to, the other use of the term for the way developers can interact with software, described here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface (The fetch API is just one of many examples of the latter, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

API stands for *application programming interface*. It is something that a program can programmatically "talk to" to get data or make something happen. That can be local within a specific programming environment, like the `fetch` API of Javascript, or it can be a remote API you can programmatically send a network request to. The principle is the same in both cases, a defined interface you can contact in a specified manner to make specific things happen.

Answer (score 1):

API stands for Application Programming Interface. The term API always means the same in these various instances, however there many types of API that define different methods of communication/interaction between software/program components.

So in the case of a REST API it is not a server that you fetch data from, it is (just like the Fetch API) a way to fetch data from the server. The API provides an easy way to communicate with the server that contains the data.